# Groovy named parameters in traits

Tags: groovy, named-parameters

Given example with `@NamedVariant` groovy transform - everything works as expected:

```
import groovy.transform.NamedVariant

class A {
    @NamedVariant
    def func(String key1 = "val1", String key2 = "val2") {
        print "key1=$key1, key=$key2"
    }
}

new A().func(key2: "xxx")
```

but when I move the `func` to a trait like this:

```
import groovy.transform.NamedVariant

class A implements B {}

trait B {
    @NamedVariant
    def func(String key1 = "val1", String key2 = "val2") {
        print "key1=$key1, key=$key2"
    }
}

new A().func(key2: "xxx")
```

It fails to compile with this error message:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: -1: Error during @NamedVariant processing. Class B$Trait$Helper already has a named-arg method of type [org.codehaus.groovy.ast.Parameter@6fd1660[name: namedArgs, type: java.util.Map, hasDefaultValue: false]]
 @ line -1, column -1.
```

Does groovy support `@NamedVariant` transform inside traits or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So taking your excerpt using traits doesn't work, but not for the same reason you posted.  I'm seeing @NamedVariant on Trait B results in a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: A.func() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[key2:xxx]]`

Comment: Maybe it varies depending on the Groovy version? I'm running on 4.0.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [groovy docs on traits and AST transformations](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_compatibility_with_ast_transformations):

> Traits are not officially compatible with AST transformations. Some of them, like @CompileStatic will be applied on the trait itself (not on implementing classes), while others will apply on both the implementing class and the trait. There is absolutely no guarantee that an AST transformation will run on a trait as it does on a regular class, so use it at your own risk!

`NamedVariant` is an AST transformation which in essence means that the groovy docs are telling us there is no guarantee this will work.

We can validate that `NamedVariant` is an AST transformation by looking at the source for `NamedVariant` [here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/e2ff7dbe3f82c9f8fbdd7186184f8530fb6b55b2/src/main/java/groovy/transform/NamedVariant.java#L4) and [here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/e2ff7dbe3f82c9f8fbdd7186184f8530fb6b55b2/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/NamedVariantASTTransformation.java#L83).